# Selecting only the terms whose exponents add up to a specific number

Tags: series-expansion, filtering, rule

Suppose I have the expression from a truncated series:

```
expr = x^8 (y^2/20160 + y^4/241920 + y^6/7257600 + y^8/406425600) + 
 x^6 (y^2/360 + y^4/4320 + y^6/129600 + y^8/7257600) + 
 x^4 (y^2/12 + y^4/144 + y^6/4320 + y^8/241920) + 
 x^2 (y^2 + y^4/12 + y^6/360 + y^8/20160)
```

How do I select only the terms where the addition of the exponents of `x` and `y` is a given number `n`? That is, the terms `x^a y^b` where `a+b=n`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the usual scaling trick. For example, to extract the terms where the exponents add up to 8:

```
SeriesCoefficient[expr /. {x -> s x, y -> s y}, {s, 0, 8}]
```

> 1/720 (2 x^6 y^2 + 5 x^4 y^4 + 2 x^2 y^6)

or:

```
Coefficient[expr /. {x -> s x, y -> s y}, s^8]
```

> (x^6 y^2)/360 + (x^4 y^4)/144 + (x^2 y^6)/360